# Fastlane checkout new branch

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, fastlane, continuous-delivery

I have been trying to create a lane for creating a new branch with my fastfile. As far as I have tried in order to run git commands, I have to use the "sh" command in fast file like this: `sh("git", "checkout", "-b","ANewBranch")`

Is there a plugin to remove this dependency of using the sh and double quotes?

Also I have been trying to run the "[git_branch](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/git_branch/)" action form my fast file but it does not work. Other actions like "increment_build_number" work as expected. Here is the fastfile:

```
lane :createBranch do | options |
    if options[:branchName]
        sh("git", "checkout", "-b", options[:branchName])
        git_branch
    else
        UI.user_error!("Send the branch name as: <fastlane createBranch branchName:NewBranchName>")
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question. But if someone is wondering how to do this, checkout [this](https://github.com/chdzq/fastlane-plugin-git_switch_branch) Fastlane plugin.